# Установка внешних ключей через web-интерфейс phpMyAdmin'a

Tags: php

Ситуация следующая:
сервер БД: MySQL 5.....
версия phpMyAdmin 3.3.10
Есть "главная" БД. Пусть имя ей - mainDb, есть (в теории) бесконечно много баз данных db_1, db_2 и т.д.
Все таблицы типа InnoDB.

В конфиг-файле строчки типа $cnf.....['pma'], $cnf.....['pmadb'], $cnf.....['pma_relation'] закомменчены.

Задача: установить через web-интерфейс phpMyAdmin'a внешний ключ например для поля db_1.component.type_id на поле mainDb.type.type_id.

Сейчас "Структура"->"Связи" есть возможность устанавливать связи на поля таблиц текущей БД. Куда посмотреть? Куда нажать? Ткните носом, пожалуйста. Нужно научиться устанавливать ключи на поля таблиц любой БД.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос снят. Как выяснилось это сделать невозможно. Только ручками прописывать внешние ключи на поля таблиц внешних БД